# how to Use GWT RPC in env with separated server: static content server and dynamic content server

Tags: gwt, rpc

Try to use GWT RPC in our application. Our application serve static 
content and dynamic content with different base url. for example, url 
to foo.jsp may have `http://localhost/context/foo.jsp` served by 
websphere, for img/js inside that jsp, we will have url like 
`http://localhost/uistatic/foo.js`, served by iis, and GWT generated 
code will be included as `http://localhost/uistatic/`......

Now, when using GWT RPC, the modulebaseurl GWT default will actually 
point to `http://localhost/uistatic/` which is not correct one, for 
calling rpc service, we can override ServiceEntryPoint by doing 
following (using HostPageBaseURL):

```
serviceDef.setServiceEntryPoint(GWT.getHostPageBaseURL() + 
GWT.getModuleName() + ......);
```

However, to use serializable DTO for rpc call, GWT load serialization 
policy file by using modulebaseurl which again is wrong (`http://localhost/uistatic/`), anyone know how to override it, or any other 
suggestion are welcome.

Thx

Answer (score 1):

From http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/1.6/FAQ_Server.html#Does_the_GWT_RPC_system_support_the_use_of_java.io.Serializable

> RPC now generates a serialization policy file during GWT compilation. The serialization policy file contains a whitelist of allowed types which may be serialized. Its name is a strong hash name followed by .gwt.rpc. In order to enable support for java.io.Serializable, the types that your application will send over the wire must be included in the serialization policy whitelist. Also, the serialization policy file must be deployed to your web server as a public resource, accessible from a RemoteServiceServlet via ServletContext.getResource(). If it is not deployed properly, RPC will run in 1.3.3 compatibility mode and refuse to serialize types implementing java.io.Serializable.

Perhaps you can override/intercept the call to getResource.

Also Check this out...http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/1.6/FAQ_Server.html#What_is_the_Same_Origin_Policy,_and_how_does_it_affect_GWT?

Michael

Answer (score 0):

You can override doGetSerializationPolicy in your RemoteServiceServlets to control how the policy file is loaded.